Why is my GitLab throwing this error when I do a merge request, causing the build of my Flutter app in the CI/CD pipeline to fail
I am encountering an error:
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
  > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':fluttertoast' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
  > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':fluttertoast' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 2m 34s
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Failed to notify root build lifecycle listener.
> Could not update /root/.gradle/caches/8.9/file-changes/last-build.bin
> Could not update /builds/be-rental/be-rental-app/android/.gradle/8.9/fileChanges/last-build.bin
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 2m 34s
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not write cache value to '/root/.gradle/daemon/8.9/registry.bin'.
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

while trying to perform a merge request in my GitLab CI/CD pipeline. The error occurs during the build process, specifically when trying to build the Flutter app bundle (flutter build app bundle). The issue seems to be related to several Gradle tasks, dependencies, and possibly the configuration of Kotlin versions used in the project. The logs indicate issues with resolving dependencies, including failing to create or transform some necessary files like kotlin-annotation-processing-gradle and kotlin-compiler-embeddable. Additionally, there are cache and permission-related issues reported by Gradle.
It would be really helpful if you could guide me through resolving this issue. Specifically, I need assistance with understanding why the Kotlin-related files are causing issues, how to fix the dependency resolution problems, and if there's any misconfiguration in my GitLab CI/CD pipeline that might be contributing to this. Any tips on how to ensure that Gradle, Flutter, and Kotlin versions are compatible, and if there are any specific changes I need to make in the pipeline configuration, would be highly appreciated.

hi, share your code as the plain text format
